# creating trigger for data transfer in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 3 tables in Oracle db,table structure is as below,an application will write 20k rows in Tnx_tmp table once all records are entered application will update Status table by updating filename and flag field with name and status "U".once status is "U".All these 20K rows needs to be copied to Tnx table and flag filed of Status table to be updated as "P".
Each row is uniquely identified by RNO.
Another app is reading the Tnx table and updating the STAT field 
As soon as the STAT field is "X" same needs to be updated in Tnx_tmp table,once all the 20k rows of Tnx_tmp is updated to "X"  and Status table should be updated with filename and flag field with  status "C" .

As i am new to Oracle Please let me know how to proceed.Should i use trigger or there is any other way.

1) Tnx_tmp

```
Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PRID                                         VARCHAR2(4)
 TYPE                                            VARCHAR2(2)
 PRCD                                          VARCHAR2(2)
 TCD                                            VARCHAR2(5)
 RNO                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 FNO                                           VARCHAR2(17)
 TNO                                             VARCHAR2(17)
 TAMT                                             VARCHAR2(14)
 NARRATION                                          VARCHAR2(50)
 JNO                                          VARCHAR2(9)
 TDT                                              DATE
 STAT                                               VARCHAR2(2)
 ERRNO                                              VARCHAR2(4)
 ERRDESC                                            VARCHAR2(100)
 STAT1                                              CHAR(1)
 PACK                                               CHAR(2)
 RMSG                                           VARCHAR2(200)
 QUPDTIME                                           VARCHAR2(15)
 QOUTTIME                                           VARCHAR2(15)
 RESPODTTIME                                        VARCHAR2(17)
 APPREAD                                            CHAR(1)
 OUTQNAME                                           CHAR(1)
 FILENAME                                           VARCHAR2(15)
```

2)Status

```
FILENAME                                           VARCHAR2(15)
FLAG                                               VARCHAR2(3)
```

3)Tnx

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PRID                                         VARCHAR2(4)
 TYPE                                            VARCHAR2(2)
 PRCD                                          VARCHAR2(2)
 TCD                                            VARCHAR2(5)
 RNO                                     NOT NULL VARCHAR2(25)
 FNO                                           VARCHAR2(17)
 TNO                                             VARCHAR2(17)
 TAMT                                             VARCHAR2(14)
 NARRATION                                          VARCHAR2(50)
 JNO                                          VARCHAR2(9)
 TDT                                              DATE
 STAT                                               VARCHAR2(2)
 ERRNO                                              VARCHAR2(4)
 ERRDESC                                            VARCHAR2(100)
 STAT1                                              CHAR(1)
 PACK                                               CHAR(2)
 RMSG                                           VARCHAR2(200)
 QUPDTIME                                           VARCHAR2(15)
 QOUTTIME                                           VARCHAR2(15)
 RESPODTTIME                                        VARCHAR2(17)
 APPREAD                                            CHAR(1)
 OUTQNAME                                           CHAR(1)
```

Comment: Usually triggers should not be used to provide complex business rules, better use functions and procedures for that. Did you start with anything or do you like us to write your entire application?

Comment: since i am new to oracle i started with trigger but found it difficult to handle all the scenarios hence was stuck

Comment: Only use triggers if it's absolutely necessary. Especially don't use triggers for your business logic. Just make a package that is used for copying from file to tnx_tmp and then from tnx_tmp etc according to your set flags and exit your process as soon as something went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect solution to use `PROCEDURE`s to solve.

I would create a [`PACKAGE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/create_package.htm#LNPLS01371) so you can bundle all the `PROCEDURE`s into an easily maintainable section of code.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE temporary_transactions_pkg
AS
  PROCEDURE load_temporary_transaction (
    p_PRID        TXN_TMP.PRID%TYPE,
    p_TYPE        TXN_TMP.TYPE%TYPE,
    p_PRCD        TXN_TMP.PRCD%TYPE,
    p_TCD         TXN_TMP.TCD%TYPE
    -- ..... more variables
  );

  PROCEDURE update_status_table (
    p_FILENAME    STATUS.FILENAME%TYPE,
    p_FLAG        STATUS.FLAG%TYPE
  );
END temporary_transactions_pkg;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY temporary_transactions_pkg
AS
  PROCEDURE load_temporary_transaction (
    p_PRID        TXN_TMP.PRID%TYPE,
    p_TYPE        TXN_TMP.TYPE%TYPE,
    p_PRCD        TXN_TMP.PRCD%TYPE,
    p_TCD         TXN_TMP.TCD%TYPE
    -- ..... more variables
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO TXN_TMP
      ( PRID, TYPE, PRCD, TCD )
    VALUES
      ( p_PRID, p_TYPE, p_PRCD, p_TCD );
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN others THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( 'TODO - Handle Exception' );
  END load_temporary_transaction;

  PROCEDURE update_status_table (
    p_FILENAME    STATUS.FILENAME%TYPE,
    p_FLAG        STATUS.FLAG%TYPE
  )
  AS
  BEGIN
      STATUS Status
      SET    FILENAME = p_FILENAME,
             FLAG     = p_FLAG;

      INSERT INTO TXN
      SELECT * FROM TXN_TMP;

      --
      -- TODO complete with your business logic.
      --
  END update_status_table;
END temporary_transactions_pkg;
```